# Ubuntu - Destkop Sharing History

Tags: networking

Hello is there any way to view the history of all the remote connections made by the built-in application called **Destkop Sharing** ?

i would like to make sure myself that there was not connection made between me and anyone else.

Im looking for some log files which if there was a connection made will contain time and ip or atleast the information that somebody has connected... thanks

Answer (score 0):

***Authorization Log***

The Authorization Log tracks usage of authorization systems, the mechanisms for authorizing users which prompt for user passwords, such as the Pluggable Authentication Module (PAM) system, the sudo command, remote logins to sshd and so on. The Authorization Log file may be accessed at **/var/log/auth.log**. This log is useful for learning about user logins and usage of the sudo command.

Use grep to cut down on the volume. For example, to see only information in the Authorization Log pertaining to sshd logins, use this:

```
grep sshd /var/log/auth.log | less
```